# Regex and exlude matches with "this" string

Tags: regex

I am trying to generate a regex string that I can't seem to get right.

I want to match any lines containing `-AS-` AND `-CO` while excluding `-DC-`

```
CCO-AS-02-CO
EKY-2F-AS-02-CO
LKS-AS-06-CO
LKS-AS-DC-07
LKS-AS-52-CR
ATX-A2-DC-AS-08-CO
BAL-0F-AS-06-CO
BAL-2F-AS-03-CO
CNC-1F-AS-05-CO
```

I'm not familiar with how to perform and but know that the this works for the containing chunks: `(.*AS.*CO)`

Help?

Comment: What programming language or text editor are you using to execute the regex? Different regex implementations have different features.

Comment: Perl, Sorry should have included that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this purely with lookaheads:

```
^(?=.*-AS-)(?=.*-CO)(?!.*-DC-).*$

                              ^^ a line with:
                       ^^^ do not have -DC- in the line
               ^^^ do have -CO
   ^^^ do have -AS-
^ Anchor, start of line
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yI5vS9/1)

The three terms can be in any order on the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?!.*-DC-).*-AS-.*-CO.*$
```

You can use `lookahead` .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/32

Answer (score 0):

If the `AS` and `CO` could be out of order, this could detect their presence.

```
^(?!.*-DC(?=-|$))(?=.*-AS(?=-|$))(?=.*-CO(?=-|$)).+$
```